# Vue: How to clear filter after applying it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in my Vue js code below i created a filter so when i click on category it filters to show only related ones and it works fine, but i wanted to add button that clears filter after being clicked with function ClearFiler() (reset to show every questions with out filter)but it's not working, is there a way to do it?

and thanks in advance

```html
<template>

<div class="container" width=800px>

  <b-row>
  <b-col cols="8">
  <h1> Recently Asked </h1>


     <ul class="container-question" v-for="(question1,index) in questions" :key="index"  
  >
    
   <li >
     {{question1.question}}

 

  <b-row>
   <div class="category" v-for="(categoryy,index) in category(question1)" v-bind:key="index" @click="selectedAnswer(categoryy)">
 
   {{ categoryy }}
   
    
       </div> 

    
  </b-row>
<b-row>


     
  </b-row>
     </li></ul>

  </b-col>
  <b-col>

   
        <div>
  
</div>
  </b-col>

  </b-row>
<router-view />

 </div>

   
</template>
<script>
export default {

  
    data(){
    return{
      questions: [],
       answered: null,
      index: 0,
     selectedIndex: null,
     
     
    }
  },

 watch: {
    question1: {

      handler() {
        this.selectedIndex = null;
       
      },
    },
  },
methods: {

      selectedAnswer(index) {
      this.selectedIndex = index;
      this.questions=this.questions.filter((question) => question.incorrect_answers.includes(index))
      console.log(index)
   
       

    },
    ClearFilter()
    {
      this.question=this.questions //not working
    }

},


  mounted: function(){
fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=9&difficulty=medium&type=multiple',{
  method: 'get'
})
.then((response) => {
  return response.json()
})
.then((jsonData) => {
  this.questions = jsonData.results
})
  }

}


    

</script>
```

Comment: Try `this.questions = []`. If you want to reset something always keep in the back of your head the initial default value, which in your case is an empty array. Right now you're setting the value to be the current value, so basically nothing happens.

Comment: i tried this empty array but also it returns empty page , while i want it to show all questions like in    {{question1.question}}

Comment: Mhh.. looking into it, in your code you have `this.question=this.questions`, there is a missing **s** there, you see that? It should be `questions` not `question`, since `question` is not a reactive data in your component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make styling changes accordingly.

```js
new Vue({
      el: '#app',
     data() {
    return {
      questions: null,
      selCategory: "all"
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filterQuestions() {
      return this.selCategory === "all"
        ? this.questions
        : this.questions.filter((item) => item.category === this.selCategory);
    },
    categories() {
      const allCat = this.questions.map((item) => item.category);
      return allCat.filter((item, pos) => {
        return allCat.indexOf(item) == pos;
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    fetch(
      "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&difficulty=medium&type=multiple"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((resp) => {
        this.questions = resp.results;
      });
  },
      
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
 <div id="app">
    <div v-if="questions">
    <h1>Recently Asked</h1>
    Filter by Category:
    <select v-model="selCategory">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option v-for="cat in categories" :value="cat">{{ cat }}</option>
    </select>
    <hr />
    <table>
      <th><td>Category</td></th>
     <th><td>Question</td></th>
      <tr v-for="(question, index) in filterQuestions" :key="index">
        <td>{{ question.category }}</td>
        <td>
          <p>{{ question.question }}</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
    Loading...
    </div>
  </div>
```